# Covariance mixed model

Tags: self-study, mixed-model

Hi I'm learning about mixed model (2x2 cross over trial) and I don't understand how this works; How do we get to the last part of Covariance where Cov(Ek(i), Ek(i)) = Var(Ek(i)) = between subject variability.
Please can you explain step by step how we get this. Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reference to the textbook you are reading, esp. since you don't explain any of the notation. Otherwise, $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X) = \operatorname{Var}(X)$ is a property of the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: The book is Bioequivalence and Statistics in clinical trials by Scott Paterson. I don't understand how this equasion is transformed. It is also described in another book Applied Mixed Models in Medicine by H. Brown and R. Prescott. It describes covariance for when two samples from the same patients are considered and I don't quite understand from where we get to the point Cov is equal to varaince between patients.

Answer (score 0):

In this model, the covariance between *two responses from the same subject* in different periods is the same as the covariance between *two responses from two subjects in the same group* (in the same or different periods).

The reason is that (a) the *group* random component $\xi_{k(i)}$ for subject $k$ in group $i$ doesn't change with time: it's shared by all subjects in $i$ across all periods; and (b) there is no *subject* random component that would be shared by all responses by the same subject.

Let's derive three covariances:

*group $i$ / subject $k$ / period $j$*

$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left( y_{ijk},y_{ijk} \right) = \operatorname{Var}\left( y_{ijk} \right) = \operatorname{Var}\left( \xi_{k(i)} \right) + \operatorname{Var}\left( \epsilon_{ijk} \right) = \sigma_B^2 + \sigma_W^2
$$

*group $i$ / subjects $k_1$ and $k_2$ / period $j$*

$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left( y_{ijk_1},y_{ijk_2} \right) =  \operatorname{Cov}\left( \xi_{k_1(i)} + \epsilon_{ijk_1} , \xi_{k_2(i)} + \epsilon_{ijk_2} \right) = \operatorname{Var}\left( \xi_{k(i)} \right) + \operatorname{Cov}\left( \epsilon_{ijk_1}, \epsilon_{ijk_2} \right) = \sigma_B^2
$$

*group $i$ / subject $k$ / periods $j_1$ and $j_2$*

$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left( y_{ij_1k},y_{ij_2k} \right) =  \operatorname{Cov}\left( \xi_{k(i)} + \epsilon_{ij_1k} , \xi_i + \epsilon_{ij_2k} \right)  = \operatorname{Var}\left( \xi_{k(i)} \right) + \operatorname{Cov}\left( \epsilon_{ij_1k}, \epsilon_{ij_2k} \right) = \sigma_B^2
$$